# TwitterやFacebookでユーザが投稿したことを確認する

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-framework

現在SNS周りの機能を作っているのですが、ユーザがTwitterやFacebookやLineのタイムラインに投稿したことを確認する方法はありますか？Facebookなどへ投稿する際にダイアログの投稿ボタンを押すと、投稿が成功した旨を伝えるアラートを表示させたいのですが、調べてもやり方が見つからず困っています。どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SLComposeViewController`を使用しているのであれば`completionHandler`プロパティを設定して、ハンドラ―内で処理を行えばよいかと思います。

```
viewController.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // 処理
    });
};
```

また`SLRequest`の場合は`performRequestWithHandler:`の引数にハンドラ―を指定します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。SLComposeViewControllerを使用しているので、ご提示いただいた方法でまず実装してみたいと思います。

Comment: ご提示いただいた方法で実装したところ、TwitterとFacebookで投稿を確認することができました！誠にありがとうございます！
ちなみになのですが、Lineで投稿を確認することはできるのでしょうか？

Comment: LINEは詳しくないのですが、どうもWebサービスではなく`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:]`で投稿しているようなので無理だと思います。

Comment: そうですよね、やはり僕も色々やっていたのですがどうしても無理でした。すみません、この度は誠にありがとうございました。